# SPRESENSEでSDカードが認識されない

Tags: arduino, spresense

SPRESENEに拡張ボードを接続し、Arduio IDE on WindowsでのLEDのサンプルは正常に動作しています。

micro SDカードはFAT32でフォーマットしており（容量は2Gと16Gのもので試行）パーティションは設定していません。

拡張ボード側のUSBに接続する（メインボードと両方同時に同じPCに差しています）とドライブはリムーバブルディスクとしてエクスプローラーに表示されますが、開こうとするとリムーバブルディスクにディスクを挿入してくださいというダイアログが出ます。
この状態でSDカードを抜き差ししても変化ありません。

スケッチ例にある、UsbMscAndFileOperationでも当然ながらファイルは見えません。

```
>>> Start File Operation
file open error
Size    Filename
----    --------
<<< Finish File Operation
>>> Start USB Mass Storage Operation
Finish USB MSC? (y/n)
<<< Finish USB Mass Storage Operation
```

なにか解決につながる知見をいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 4):

関係ないかもしれませんが、メインボードと拡張ボードの間の物理的な接続は問題ないでしょうか。

わたしのばあい接続具合が悪く、SDカードが認識されないエラーにハマりました。
しっかりとはめ込むことで認識されるようになりました。

Comment: ご指摘を受けて、もう一度メインボードを上から加圧してみたところ、わずかに挿入感がありました！その後、再接続したところ認識しました！！ありがとうございます。OSはMacOS 10.13.6で認識できています。

Answer (score 2):

SPRESENSE の Arduino Lib のバージョンはいくつですか？私は、1.0.1 ですが問題なくアクセスできました。サンプルスケッチの UsbMscAndFileOperation を使っています。Host PC のOS は Windows10 です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。原因は物理的な接続状態でしたが、Arduino Libは、1.0.0でしたので、アップデートしたいと思います。