# Spresenseの拡張ボードが反応しなくなりました。

Tags: spresense

CircuitPythonでSpresenseを動かそうっとしています。使っているPCはMac Book Airで、OSはBig Surです。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/circuitpython_set_up_en.html

上のリンクを参考して作業を進んでいたところ、Spresenseのメインボード上の4つのLEOを光らせる事ができるようになりました。
しかし、code.pyの中身を以下のコードのように書き換えてみたら、突然拡張ボードへの読み込みが止まり、繋がっているはずのCIRCUITPYデバイスも消えました。以降拡張ボードのUSBを挿し直してもCIRCUITPYデバイスが出てきてくれませんでした。（電源の青いLEOは光っています。）

```
import board
import digitalio
import time
from ulab import numpy as np

start = time.time()

led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.LED0)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

b = np.array(range(25), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((5, 5))
print("b", b)
counter = 0

for i in range(5):
    led.value = True
    time.sleep(0.5)
    led.value = False
    time.sleep(0.5)
    counter += 1

print("counter", counter)
process_time = time.time() - start
print("time [s] =", process_time)
```

以下の部分をコードに追加した途端、書き込みができなくなったので、この部分が原因ではないかと疑っていますが、よくわからないです…

```
start = time.time()
```

```
process_time = time.time() - start
print("time [s] =", process_time)
```

Mu editorでコードを書いていましたので、logを確認すると

```
2021-10-15 15:08:39,220 - mu.logic:1207(save_tab_to_file) ERROR: [Errno 6] Device not configured
2021-10-15 15:08:39,257 - mu.interface.main:1038(show_message) DEBUG: ファイルを保存できませんでした(ディスクの問題)。
2021-10-15 15:08:39,257 - mu.interface.main:1039(show_message) DEBUG: ディスクへのファイルの保存でエラーになりました。ファイルの書込み権とディスクの空きが十分にあるかを確認してください。
2021-10-15 15:08:39,404 - mu.modes.base:136(close) INFO: Closing connection to REPL on port: /dev/cu.usbmodem8793CC766F1
2021-10-15 15:08:39,408 - mu.interface.main:1038(show_message) DEBUG: デバイスが繋げられていないようです。
2021-10-15 15:08:39,408 - mu.interface.main:1039(show_message) DEBUG: デバイスがこのコンピュータに繋げられているかを確認してください。

REPL が動作するには、MicroPython (または CircuitPython)がデバイスに転送されている必要があります。

最後に、デバイスのリセットボタンを押してから、もう一度試してください。
2021-10-15 15:09:03,685 - mu.logic:730(check_usb) INFO: circuitpython device disconnected on port: /dev/cu.usbmodem8793CC766F1(VID: 0x054C, PID: 0x0BC2, manufacturer Sony)
```

のようにエラーが出てきていました。

別のMac PCで試しても同じく拡張ボードと繋がりません。

記述が悪く、フラッシュメモリが破損した事が原因でしょうか？
何方かアドバイスをいただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Spresense拡張ボードとメインボードのコネクタの物理的な接続の問題かもしれません。スタックオーバーフローで過去に似たような質問がありました。こちらはSDカードですが、USBコネクタも同じ問題の可能性があります。

[SPRESENSEでSDカードが認識されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47367/spresense%E3%81%A7sd%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%98%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/47427#47427)

もし、メインボードを拡張ボードに強く押し付けても症状が改善しない場合は、Recovery Tool を試すとよいかもしれません。私は Arduino 環境を使っているのですが、プログラムを書き込んでも反映されないときがあり、このツールによくお世話になっています。

[Spresense のシリアルモニタに "D>" と表示されてしまう、またはボードへの書き込みに失敗する](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/faq_ja.html#_spresense_%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AB_d_%E3%81%A8%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)